# Error: Cannot find module './undefined' with discord-buttons, discord.js, TypeScrpit and webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, discord.js, discord-buttons

I use TypeScript and Webpack for my Discord bot. It used to compile with no problems, until I tried to use [discord-buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons).

I've found some questions and answers about discord.js, TypesScript and Webpack. But no one of them say something about discord-buttons.

The `module.exports` in my webpack config file looks like this:

```js
entry: {
    index: {
      import: "./src/index.ts",
      dependOn: ["discord", "buttons"]
    },
    discord: "discord.js",
    buttons: "discord-buttons"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
},
output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
},
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, ],
},
target: "node",
externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

My `index.ts` file does nothing with `discord-buttons` but importing it and using `disbut`

```js
import { Client, Message, MessageEmbed, TextChannel } from "discord.js"
import disbut from 'discord-buttons'

const token:string = `token`
const client: Client = new Client()
disbut(client)

client.login(token)
```

When I build with Webpack (in development mode), it says there is no error, but I get one when I run the `index.bundle.js`

```sh
> webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.dev.js

asset index.bundle.js 75.4 KiB [emitted] (name: index)
asset buttons.bundle.js 6.75 KiB [compared for emit] (name: buttons)
asset discord.bundle.js 6.72 KiB [compared for emit] (name: discord)
runtime modules 5.42 KiB 16 modules
built modules 62.7 KiB [built]
  cacheable modules 62.6 KiB
    modules by path ./src/modules/*.ts 48.5 KiB
      ./src/modules/CommandManager.ts 19.8 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./src/modules/OutputManager.ts 2.05 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./src/modules/LogManager.ts 3.59 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./src/modules/FirebaseManager.ts 17.9 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./src/modules/SpikeChannels.ts 5.17 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/index.ts 11.8 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./spike-database-firebase-admin-ETC.json 2.26 KiB [built] [code generated]
  external "discord.js" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "discord-buttons" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "fastest-levenshtein" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "firebase-admin" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.46.0 compiled successfully in 4242 ms

> spike-bot@1.0.0 bot
> node ./dist/index.bundle.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
Require stack:
- /home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js
- /home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/index.bundle.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.f.require (/home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js:157:28)
    at /home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js:84:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.e (/home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js:83:67)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.X (/home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js:121:22) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js',
    '/home/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/index.bundle.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Install [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) and run with `node -r source-map-support/register ./dist/index.bundle.js` to get proper stacktraces, mapped to the original code.

Comment: I still get `Error: Cannot find module './undefined'` :( @KelvinSchoofs

Comment: Yes, but now the stacktrace should be different, no? So you can see what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: It says the line that causes this problem is discord.bundle.js:121:22 (`Function.__webpack_require__.X (/home/eban/PATH_TO_PROJECT/dist/discord.bundle.js:121:22)
`), which is `chunkIds.map(__webpack_require__.e, __webpack_require__)`. As I don't understand much about this, I don't know what this error means. @KelvinSchoofs

Comment: Not sure then. The only thing that looks strange and possibly wrong to me is either the `nodeExternals()` bit or the part where you add an entrypoint for two external modules.

Comment: You're right, it's contradictory, since I use node externals for not adding node_modules to the bundle, but then I add them to entry. I just removed those from entry and all compiled and executed with no error haha

Comment: I'll make an answer for that, so this question can be marked as having a solution then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you added entry points for external modules, namely your `discord` and `buttons` entry points. Entry points should be for your own scripts, usually not externals. If you're not planning on running multiple processes, a single entry point is also all you need.